# How to prevent slideToggle from repeating itself when being triggered many times by hover?

Tags: jquery, html, css, cursor, slidetoggle

So, I got a list of images, and some Lorem Ipsum text is going to show up every time the mouse pass over the **li** elements. But if you change quickly the mouse position from one to another list element, the slideToggle keeps leaving and coming as many times as you hovered the element.

Also: when the cursor goes on the **p** element, which is the one that show up, it keeps on movement, because it's not recognized like the mouse is over the **li**, only the **p**. How can I avoid that?

[My demo on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6r4g7Lph/2/)

Thank you <3

```js
$('#tabela_trabalhos ul li').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).find('p').slideToggle(200)
    
})

$('#tabela_trabalhos ul li').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).find('p').fadeOut(400)
    
})
```

```css
#tabela_trabalhos {
    margin-top: 32px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}

#tabela_trabalhos ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
}

    #tabela_trabalhos ul li {
        width:100%;
        height:100px;
        background: #aaa;
        transition:1s;
    }

        #tabela_trabalhos ul li:hover {
            background:#888;
            transition:0.2s;
            cursor:pointer;
        }

        #tabela_trabalhos ul li p {
            display:none;
            color:white;
            margin:25px 0 0 25px;
            font-size:20px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabela_trabalhos">
                <ul>
                    <li><p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</p></li>
                    <li><p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</p></li>
                    <li><p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</p></li>
                </ul>

                <ul>
                    <li><p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</p></li>
                    <li><p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</p></li>
                    <li><p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</p></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `mouseenter` instead of `mouseover` and you can use [`finish()`](http://api.jquery.com/finish/) to make sure any prior animation stops immediately

```
$('#tabela_trabalhos ul li').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).find('p').finish().slideToggle(200);        
});

$('#tabela_trabalhos ul li').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).find('p').finish().fadeOut(400);        
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/m8up2o3s/)**</kbd>